# Solving the second derivative of this equation

Tags: derivatives

So I have the equation

$$\tan^2 \theta = \frac{x^2+y^2}{z^2}$$

I got the first derivative of $\theta$ with respect to $x$ by doing this

\begin{align}
2\sec^2 \theta \tan  \theta d \theta &= \frac{2x}{z^2} dx \\
\frac{d \theta}{dx} &= \frac{x \cos^3 \theta}{z^2 \sin \theta}
\end{align}

But I'm having difficulty solving for $\frac{d^2\theta}{dx^2}$. Any help?

Comment: $\displaystyle{\frac{d^2\theta}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d\theta}{dx}}$

Comment: Differentiate again and put the value of $d\theta /dx$ and then express everything in $tan\theta$. Replace the value of $tan\theta$ from the question to get the answer.